# Problems of LED drive circuit and FET selection

Tags: led

The circuit was configured as follows to drive 7 LEDs.
Please review the circuit diagram to make sure there are no problems.
Is it okay to use the 2N7002K FET?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pretty marginal. I would replace the driver with an [AO3400A](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/1133/AO3400A_ds.pdf) or similar. You can drive it directly with a 3.3V GPIO and avoid the two pullups and second transistor.

The [2N7002](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds11303.pdf) has maximum 120mA Ids with 10V (not 5V) drive and Ta = 85°C. You don't say what the LED Vf spec is, but if they are 2V each that would be more than 250mA. If they are 3V it would be more like 128mA.

Answer (score 0):

Leds are on when microcontroller output is low and on microcontroller output high, leds are off. 2N7002K will not work as mentioned by Hearth below.

Comment: No you cannot. The absolute maximum drain current of the 2N7002 is 380 mA, and that's with a very large drain pad to sink heat. You definitely can't pull 1.4 A--but I'm not sure you need to.